# Vue 3 migrate why computed property dont work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

hello I have image in template :

```
<img :src="imageUrl" />
```

user on start

```
const user = ref(null);
```

load user on start

```
onBeforeMount(async () => {
    user.value = await api();
})
```

and placeholder on start while is not loaded

```
import placeholder from '@/assets/placeholder-image.png';

    const imageUrl = computed(() => {
        if(!user.value){
            return placeholder;
        }
        if (user.value.image.startsWith('http')) {
            return user.value.image;
        }
        return `//localhost/${user.value.image}`;
    });
```

Eventually I take placeholder -> load user -> placeholder don't change!

Why don't work computed property ?

Comment: What's the actual value of `imageUrl` when you've loaded the user? Is it a valid URL? Can you enter that URL directly into the browser's address bar and see the image?

Comment: @tony19 100% url is valid

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: if your api is a module like axios, the api result will be in `data`.  So `user.value.data.image`.  You might consider adding a log statement in to dump the api value when it resolves.

Comment: Did you return `imageUrl` from your setup function?